# django blog zinnia - NoReverseMatch at /blog/

Tags: python, django, zinnia

My current project uses django blog zinnia and when I open `/blog` it gives the following error:

```
Reverse for 'zinnia_entry_add' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I tried creating a separate test project and it is working without any problems. In this test project, I tried this in shell   :

```
reverse("admin:zinnia_entry_add") which is returning '/admin/zinnia/entry/add/'
```

But, when I check the same thing in my current project it's throwing above error. I have enabled admin, I am able to access /admin too. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Along with other steps described in [docs](http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/develop/how-to/rewriting_entry_url.html) you have to [extend Entry model](http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/develop/how-to/rewriting_entry_url.html). On this step don't forget to register your new admin class, see section [Updating the admin interface](http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/develop/how-to/extending_entry_model.html#updating-the-admin-interface).

Answer (score -1):

Have you added `url(r'^weblog/', include('zinnia.urls')),` in `urls.py`? Documentation is [here](http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/latest/getting-started/install.html#urls).